# Numpy arrax of integers from decimal to binary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array: `ch=[1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 25]`

How can i write it in: `b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x14\x19'`

Note: i do not want to convert each integer to binary. Is there any function available to do it directly in one step?

Comment: ch is a numpy array

Comment: import numpy as geek
  
ch=geek.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 25])
x=bytes(ch)
print(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bytes` bult-in and pass the sequence:

```py
>>> ch=[1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 25]
>>> bytes(ch)
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x14\x19'
```

On a side note, what you are showing is a python list, not a numpy array.

But, if you want to operate on numpy array, you can first convert it to a python list:

```py
>>> bytes(np.array(ch).tolist())
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x14\x19'
```

When you directly try `to_bytes()` on the numpy array for above data:

```py
>>> np.array(ch).tobytes()
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00'
```

The above output is also right, the only difference is due to the data type, if you print it, you'll know that it's `numpy.int32`,  which is 32 bit means 32/8=4 bytes i.e. the number of bytes required to represent each of the values.

```py
>>> np.array(ch).dtype
dtype('int32')
```

If, you convert it to 8-bit i.e. 1 byte number, the output will be same, as using `bytes` bultin over a list:

```py
>>> np.array(ch).astype(np.int8).tobytes()
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x14\x19'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: Working fine on Python 3.7.5 win10

Comment: You're operating on a list. OP specifically indicated a NumPy array.

Comment: @MattDMo, but the input presented is not a numpy array.

Comment: How can we chage little or big endian?

Comment: numpy.ascontiguousarray(x, dtype='>i2')

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
b"".join([int(item).to_bytes(1, "big") for item in ch])
```

First you iterate over the NumPy array, convert each `np.int32` object to `int`, call `int.to_bytes()` on it, returning 1 byte in big-endian order (you could also use `"little"` here), then joining them all together.

Alternatively, you could call `list()` on the array, then pass it to the built-in `bytes()` constructor:

```
bytes(list(ch))
```